# How do I make the type of a generic delegate in C#/.NET 4?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

I can make the type of a delegate at runtime from a list of parameter System.Type, thanks to a answer to a question here.

But how do I do this when one of the parameters is a generic parameter, say it represents something like the following?

```
    delegate t ScanFun<t>();
```

I want a System.Type which represents a generic delegate so I can call Type.MakeGenericType method with the type for the generic parameter t. However, I can't even find a way to find out what the type of that looks like.

The use is in a code analysis tool. This is the code I have which works with known types:

```
System.Type[] parms = new Type[f.sig.Parms.list.Length + 1];
specs[0] = f.sig.ReturnType.Type;
for (int i = 0; i < f.sig.Parms.list.Length; i++)
    specs[i + 1] = f.sig.Parms.list[i].Type;
for (int i = 0; i < parmTypes_.Length; i++)
{
    if (f.sig.Generic.List.Contains(specs[i].Name))
    {
        /// TODO: Make generic parameter Type here
        goto done;
    }
    parms[i] = f.Parent.findType(specs[i]);
    done: ;
}
var dtype = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetDelegateType(parms);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Type openScanFunType = typeof(ScanFun<>);
Type closedScanFunType = openScanFunType.MakeGenericType(new[] { typeof(int) });
```

Alternatively (and this works better if there are multiple type parameters):

```
Type openScanFunType = typeof(ScanFun<string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
Type cloCsedScanFunType = openScanFunType.MakeGenericType(new[] { typeof(int) });
```

Comment: thats interesting, but it relies on having the delegate Type already.

Comment: @Colin: It is neither clear from your question nor from your comment to which this comment is a reply exactly what you are looking for then.

Comment: I have parsed a delegate definition from a file.
from that I need to create a System.Type which reflects that.

so all I have are the return type and paramater types, this is quite acheivable but when one or more parameters are generic parameters I cant see how to do it.

(sorry the press return to send feature made my comment a bit premature)

Comment: to put it in a nutshell I need the functionality of this
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetDelegateType(Type[]);
with the added ability to specify any parameter as a generic parameter.